# zshrc doesn't convert \u into hostname

Tags: macos-catalina, zshrc

There is a problem with my .zshrc file. I want to customise my .zshrc on macOS Catalina. Therefore I added the following to my .zshrc:

```
export PS1='[\u@\h \$'
```

Then I called `source .zshrc` and got the following output:

[image: Bas output]

Is there any solution to display the user and hostname properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide02.html#l19

```
PS1='%n@%m %(!:#:$) '
```

`%(!:#:$)` allows you to change the default prompt symbol from % to $ (which it seems you are wanting to do) and still keep # for root.

If you just want to keep the default zsh prompt symbol, use:

```
PS1='%n@%m %# '
```

Not sure why you have '[' in there. If you would like to use square brackets around the username and host:

```
PS1='[%n@%m] %(!:#:$) '
```

If you would like the current directory in your prompt, add `%c`.

Also there's no need to use export.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The square bracket was unnecessary. I missed the thing you mentioned with the `%`. So after I used this everything worked!